# Should I retain NSCalendar object for a persistent use?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, foundation, nscalendar

In a Calendar-like app, or part of an app, I need to use (gregorian) calendar in many routines, which means I need to alloc-init and release the same NSCalendar object for many times. Shall I retain one NSCalendar (say gregorian calendar) as an ivar(`@property(nonatomic,retain)`) in my long persistent controller instance?

Or is its instance methods re-entrant/thread-safe?

Comment: I don't see any problem with keeping one around for a while.

Comment: Although I do not have authoritative sources to prove, I still doubt if NSCalendar/NSDateFormatter are really thread-safe. I do see others' comments suggesting that they are not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, you should keep calendars and date formatters around because they are expensive to create and/or use the first time (I found this out the hard way).

However, the [Thread Safety Summary](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html) lists both NSCalendar and NSFormatter (NSDateFormatter's superclass) as “Thread-Unsafe”, saying:

> The following classes and functions are generally not thread-safe. In most cases, you can use these classes from any thread as long as you use them from only one thread at a time. Check the class documentation for additional details.

I suggest looking for a way to do both. This is one advantage of creating threads yourself using NSThread: You can stash each thread's calendar in its [thread dictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSThread/threadDictionary).

Otherwise, you'll just have to create and throw away each calendar every time and pay the performance cost.

Comment: Your reasoning seems to stand. But I will keep an eye on this issue.

Comment: Or you can utilise locking to synchronize access to your global calendar, therefore being able to access it from any thread. `@synchronized` in Objective-C and `objc_sync_enter/objc_sync_exit` in Swift. You'd use the global calendar object as the object to synchronize on.

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall That only protects that section of code, not any other code that uses the calendar but doesn't synchronize on it (including code in frameworks, including but not limited to frameworks).

Comment: As of 2014, NSCalendar is now thread-safe: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html